# Trouble with chessboard set definition

Tags: set-theory, computer-vision

The following equation is supposed to define a set of points that produces a square grid (like a chessboard).

[image]
s is the distance between each square in the grid
w and h are the dimensions of the board overall

My question is, does the dot following (x,y,0) mean multiply? If so this would produce an infinite amount of points greater than 1 and up until w,h, which isn’t a grid. I’m guessing it doesn’t mean multiply in this context and means something else, if so, what does it mean?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This quite confusing, before even getting to the meaning of the dot. What is $s$? Shouldn't $x$ and $y$ be integers? Where does this definition come from? Why do you need it?  Please [edit] the question to give us a lot more context.

Comment: I have said in the original post that s is the distance between each square in the grid.

Comment: It works if you only take integers $x,y$ (and treat $\cdot s$ as scalar multiplication).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is
$$
\{ s(x,y,0) \ | \ x, y \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } \ 0 \le  x < w, \ 0 \le y < h \}
$$
For $s=1.5, h=2, w = 3$ that produces the grid of points

```
(0,1.5,0)  (1.5,1.5,0)  (3,1.5,0) 



(0,  0,0)  (1.5,  0,0)  (3,  0,0)
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot more sense when the coordinate system is defined with integers.